# Microsoft sql 2008 string formatting

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, format

I wonder if there is something in Microsoft SQL 2008, which can do similar thing in C#

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)

    String.Format("ABC {0}  XYZ", i.ToString());
```

Basically, is the String.Format() possible in MS SQL 2008?

Just make it more clear. I want to create a table dynamicaly, so need to generate string for the columns, like

```
"Col1 FLOAT, Col2 FLOAT. Col3 FLOAT"
```

The number of column is specified by a variable, so I wonder if there is a function to do String.Format(), so I can use in a loop.

Idealy, I want to write a stored procedure, and pass in

```
"Col{0} Float"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @variable INT
Declare @columnName varchar(50)
Declare @columnType varchar(10)

Select @columnName + CONVERT(varchar(10), @variable) + ' ' + @columnType
```

here u go. assign variable to your int value and run in loop or you can create that loop in sql. i would do that in sql instead of going back and forth. but it depends on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Next version has a [`FORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28SQL.110%29.aspx) function or you can roll your own CLR function in SQL Server 2008 that calls the `.NET` framework formatting methods but for your stated use case I would just use something like the below.

```
DECLARE @ColList varchar(max) = 
               (SELECT ',Col',number+0,' FLOAT'
                FROM   master..spt_values
                WHERE  type = 'P'
                       AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
                FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT STUFF(@ColList, 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just concatenating text to a column so you can make use of +:

`SELECT "Employee Name" + EmployeeName AS EmployeeName FROM MyTable`

You do have to watch out with using + though depending on the datatype, but there is always `CAST` and `CONVERT` to help you cast datatypes to a specific type.